# Get the average values of each column after printing the output

Tags: python

I want to calculate the average value of each column when I have the output result like this [image]

I really hope some of you can help me. I really appreciate. Thank you so much.

My code :

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import glob

namefiles = glob.glob('E:\koppen-master\dat_Viet\T2m_BAICHAY_1998_2019.txt')

for g in namefiles:
    print(g)
data1=np.loadtxt(fname=g,comments="#")

nyr1=len(data1[:,1])/31    

nyr1=int(nyr1)

r3T2m=np.reshape(data1[:,1:13],(nyr1,31,12))
r2T2m_mn=np.zeros(shape=(nyr1,12))

iyr1=0    # year in consideration; remember that array indice in Python starts from 0
while iyr1 < nyr1:
        imn1=0              #month indication
        while imn1<12:
                idy1=0          #day of month
                ndy1=0          #number of day in a month without missing value
                while idy1 <31:
                        if r3T2m[iyr1][idy1][imn1]>=-10.:   # to avoid missing data -99.
                                ndy1=ndy1+1
                                r2T2m_mn[iyr1][imn1]=r2T2m_mn[iyr1][imn1]+r3T2m[iyr1][idy1][imn1]
                        idy1=idy1+1
                r2T2m_mn[iyr1][imn1]=round(r2T2m_mn[iyr1][imn1]/float(ndy1),2)
                imn1=imn1+1 

        print ("Year:",iyr1+1998,"  ",r2T2m_mn[iyr1])
        iyr1=iyr1+1
```

Comment: Do you need to perform OCR on that image first?

Comment: yes. It will be nice if you can guide me

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt',sep=" ")
df.set_index('Name of 1st column')  # This will set the 1st column as index, check now
```

You now need to create a list that has values of each column and then simply do any calculations you want.
**Hope it helps**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It have error : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'setindex'

Comment: i made a mistake here. It will be set_index

Comment: I do not understand " df.set_index('Name of 1st column')" because it cause error. Like this : KeyError: "None of [''] are in the columns"

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcViệt use this line instead :  df = pd.read_csv('file_name.txt',sep=" ",index_col=0) # if this doesn't work, try setting index_col=1